# Using Gitlab CI/CD to run command batch file

Tags: batch-file, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Using Gitlab CI/CD to run command batch file.

I have a batch file stored locally in my system. Now I want to run it from GitLab CI/CD YAML file.
I used the below format to run the YAML

```yaml
Windows:
  script:
    - call: ci\CheckStatus.bat init
    - call: ci\CheckStatus.bat build
  tags:
    - windows
```

**But it is giving me below error**

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
jobs:windows:script config should be a string or an array containing strings and arrays of strings
```

How to resolve this and call my batch file to execute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `call` keyword under script so just enter executable commands as you would use them locally:

```yaml
Windows:
  script:
    - ci\CheckStatus.bat init
    - ci\CheckStatus.bat build
  tags:
    - windows
```

Comment: I have used call keyword to call the script.                                                              
 `Windows:
  script:
    - call ci\CheckStatus.bat init
    - call ci\CheckStatus.bat build
  tags:
    - windows`                               But I am facing this error '$ call ci\CheckStatus.bat init
00:08
 call : The term 'call' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
 script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
 was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
 At line:1 char:1
 + call ci\CheckStatus.bat init`

Comment: Windows runners use powershell by default so to test it open your windows machine, powershell terminal and try executing commands there first. If they work just populate it to .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Yes first I have tried the same from Powershell, there it worked. Tried setting same in the yml file and tried to execute but facing this error `$ cd C:\Temp\notification-service
00:18
 cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Temp\notification-service' because it does not exist.
 At line:1 char:1
 + cd C:\Temp\notification-service`   Same if I try it from PS it is working

Comment: Are you testing it on the same windows machine where your gitlab runner is registered?